# Override console.log in for debug only, but it points to the override blocks, which is annoying

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am overriding my console.log to work only in debug mode like this

```
preservedConsoleLog = console.log
console.log = () ->
  preservedConsoleLog.apply(console, arguments) if MyProject.debug
```

This works fine but I still have one concern. While Chrome dev tools outputs the console results, it only points to the override definition I listed above.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter it so it only alters console.log if debug isn't enabled, like so:

```
if(!MyProject.debug){
  console.log=(function(){});
}
```

And the issue should disappear.